# How can I run JavaScript function in my HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a function in JS code, and I want to run it from HTML, but I don't see any reaction, when I run the site.

I will show you example of html code and js code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.js">
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="add()"> 
    
    <p id="add2"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Here starts JS code

```
function add(a,b,c,d) {
  return a + b + c + d;
}

document.getElementById("add2").innerHTML = add(5,10,15,20);
```

I hope I wrote it clearly and someone will tell me, what did I do wrong?

Comment: You call the function add on load. You want to trigger the code that updates the DOM onload. Something like `window.addEventListener('load', function () { document.getElementById("add2").innerHTML = add(5,10,15,20);  });`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: As a side point, your stylesheet link links to a js page.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code is in the `head`, which is before the `body` and everything else, so the JavaScript runs before the `p` element has been created (html is run line by line). To fix this issue, you can try putting the JavaScript at the end of the document, for example after `body`.

Answer (score 0):

When a browser loads an HTML page, it reads your HTML from top-to-bottom.

So ordering is important.

There are complexities of course. I'm not talking about deferred or asynchronous scripts here. But the top-to-bottom simplification helps us understand your problem.

Your script is inside `test.js`, so it will be loaded and run before [body] is ready.

But `test.js` has this line:

```js
document.getElementById("add2").innerHTML = add(5,10,15,20);
```

This line is not inside a function, so the browser will try to run it immediately.

The call to `add()` will work because it has been declared in the file. But `document.getElementById("add2")` will not, because it is an instruction to access the following HTML in the [body]:

```html
<p id="add2"></p>
```

But the [body] has not been "read" yet, so the JavaScript DOM API does not know about it.

However, you have partially solved the problem already using the `onload` attribute of the [body] tag. You've just used the wrong function with it.

That `onload` is an instruction to run a function *after* [body] has been completely read. So if you changed your `document.getElementById` line to be inside a function:

```js
function runWhenBodyHasLoaded () {
  document.getElementById("add2").innerHTML = add(5,10,15,20); 
}
```

And told the [body] tag to run the function after everything has loaded:

```html
<body onload="runWhenBodyHasLoaded()">
```

Then `<p id="add2"></p>` will be ready in time to access it with `document.getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

Or with jQuery:
https://jsfiddle.net/bdgu8s4h/1/

Also consider loading your JS at the end (of body)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body> 
    <p id="add2"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function add(a,b,c,d) {
    return a + b + c + d;
}
    $('#add2').html(add(5,10,15,20));
});
```

Hope this also helped, cheers

Comment: can you then mark an answer / vote up pls